# Running without Python source files in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

I'm trying to run a Python application without keeping the `.py` source files around, and only relying on the `.pyc` compiled files. However, I am getting import errors when I remove the `.py` source files. This functionality is working in Python 2.7, but not in 3.4 (with the new `__pycache__` structure).

Here's a sample directory structure:

> ```
> package/
>   __init__.py
>   module.py
> ```

### Python 2.7

First let's see what happens when I use Python 2.7 (this is the desired behavior)

```
$ python2 -c "from package import module"
$ find package -name "*.py" -delete
$ python2 -c "from package import module"
```

It's all good and no errors are thrown. The directory structure after doing this would look like this, with the `.pyc` files along side the original `.py` files:

> ```
> package/
>   __init__.pyc
>   module.pyc
> ```

### Python 3.4

Now, let's do the same thing with Python 3.4, starting with our original directory structure again

```
$ python3 -c "from package import module"
$ find package -name "*.py" -delete
$ python3 -c "from package import module"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: cannot import name 'module'
```

Uh oh, it can't import the module. Interestingly, I could still safely run `python3 -c "import package"` at this point, but it can't grab any modules out of there. At this point, the directory structure looks a little different than it did in 2.7, specifically like this:

> ```
> package/
>   __pycache__/
>       __init__.cpython-34.pyc
>       module.cpython-34.pyc
> ```

So the question is this: why can't Python 3.4 import/execute properly given only `.pyc` files? Is this desired behavior, meaning that the source has to be kept around in all situations? Or am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-3-pycache-foo-magic-pyc-with-no-source):

> It's possible that the foo.py file somehow got removed, while leaving the cached pyc file still on the file system. If the `__pycache__/foo.<magic>.pyc` file exists, but the foo.py file used to create it does not, Python will raise an ImportError when asked to import foo. In other words, Python will not import a pyc file from the cache directory unless the source file exists.

But:

> In order to continue to support source-less distributions though, if the source file is missing, Python will import a lone pyc file if it lives where the source file would have been.

So it would seem that `__pycache__` and sourceless distributions are mutually exclusive.  If you want to remove the source, you need to move the .pyc files out into the directory where the source would have been.

Comment: Ah, there it is! I actually tried moving the pyc files during my millions of iterations yesterday, but the issue is that I wasn't removing the `<magic>` section from the filename. So for future readers, you will need to do something along the following lines for each pyc: `mv package/__pycache__/module.cpython-34.pyc package/module.pyc`

Answer (score 37):

No enough reputation to add comment to BrenBarn's answer. So here is some complement.

According to the [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/compileall.html) doc:

> **-b**
>
> Write the byte-code files to their legacy locations and names, which may  overwrite byte-code files created by another version of Python. The default  is to write files to their PEP 3147 locations and names, which allows byte-  code files from multiple versions of Python to coexist.

So you could run `python -m compileall -b .` to compile all the code files in this directory recursively.

Comment: Thank you. This question is exactly what I need!